# Resize a table automatically in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel to register the results of particles in cleanrooms. That excel consist in a table with 3 columns and 39 rows (the most big cleanroom have this quantity of points). The first columns only contains correlative number (1 2 3 4 5...). So, I want to find a method to automatically resize the table based in a value of another cell in the same sheet.

For example, if I put a 10 in this cell, that the table, automatically, have 3 columns and 10 rows (if it is possible, the first column having the correlative numeration)

That you so much for your help. I can't put an example because I'm writing on my phone.

Comment: What do you mean by, *"resize a table?"*  Excel automatically adjusts the `UsedRange` of the table based on the values furthest down and to the right.  If you only use 3 columns and 10 rows, the table size is 3 columns and 10 rows.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation. Imagine that you have a cell where you put a value, 10 for example. I want, if it is possible, that automatically, excel build a table with 10 rows and 3 columns in a specificed location of the sheet.

Comment: Again, what do you mean "build a table?"  What data will be in the table?  Did you just want headers/row labels?  Actual data?  *What work is being done?*

Comment: OK, sorry again. I try to expose the question another time... The value "X" (10 for example) might permit to generate automatically a unique column (in a specificed position of the sheet) enumerated to 1 until 10 (one column with 10 rows). The another 2 columns have to stay empty and for this, it is not necessary to consider this columns... Sorry, I'm not sure if this is possible to do and this fact do very difficult to expose the question. Thanks.